# Why does iPhone display slide horizontally but Android does not

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone, mobile

Our website behaves differently on an Android than on an iPhone. When the website displays on an iPhone, you can slide the display from side to side. This does not happen when I test the website on Chrome, click Inspect, and choose the iPhone emulator.

I have the following meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
```

I cannot find any div or element wider than the screen width.

I have the following CSS

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Thank you

Comment: Are there any paddings or margins set on the body by the iPhone?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I myself do not have an iPhone. I make changes to the website, move them to our live website and then have my manager and the designer check the website on their iPhones. I do not know if they have settings on their iPhones. There are some paddings and margins set in css for the website but none on the body, just on some divs and other elements on the web page.

Comment: You can also have padding and margin on the html, body tag. Browsers can add their own CSS to an element making it do things you didn't expect. Just look at all the questions about a whitespace around a website because of a `padding`, `margin` on the `body` and `html`.